# The matched route does not include a 'controller' route value, which is required. while submit form

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am doing `Html.BeginForm` in partial view. In main view, I am using angular `ng-repeat` for displaying set of images. then displaying form which is in partial view.
my view:

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <div id="accordion">
            <h3>Search by Manufacturer</h3>
            <div class="manufacturerDiv">
                <ul class="manufacturerList">
                    <li ng-repeat="item in manufacturerList"><a href="/Deal/{{item.ManufacturerName}}"><img src="/Content/ModelImages/{{item.Logo}}" height="20" width="20" alt="{{item.ManufacturerName}}" /></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <h3>Search by Price</h3>                               
            @{Html.RenderAction("SearchByPrice", "Deal");}

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

My Partial view:

```
@model VC.Website.Models.SearchDealbyPriceVM
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchByPrice", "Deal", FormMethod.Post)) { 
<form id="enq_form">    
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CategoriesID, new SelectList(Model.Categories, "Key", "Value"), "Select Category", new { @class = "form-control categorydropdown" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FromPrice, new { @placeholder = "From Price £", @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ToPrice, new { @placeholder = "To Price £", @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <i class="clear_0"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-12">            
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.IsBusinessPrice, "true", new { @class = "form-control" })
            <label class="radiolabel">Business</label>            
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.IsBusinessPrice, "false", new { @class = "form-control" })
            <label class="radiolabel">Personal</label>            
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.GreenCars, new { @class = "form-control" })
            <label class="radiolabel">@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.GreenCars)</label>
        </div>
        <i class="clear_0"></i>
    </div>    
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-12 enquire_btn_wrap">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default en_btn">Enquire About this Car</button>
        </div>
        <i class="clear_0"></i>
    </div>
</form>
}
```

Controller:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchByPrice(SearchDealbyPriceVM model)
{           
    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { CategoriesID = model.CategoriesID, FromPrice = model.FromPrice, ToPrice = model.ToPrice, Price=model.IsBusinessPrice, GreenCars = model.GreenCars,PageName="SpecialGarage" });
}
```

Route.config:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute("Error", "Home/Error");
            routes.MapRoute("Deal", "Deal", defaults: new { controller = "Deal", action = "Index" });
            routes.MapRoute("DealManufacturer", "Deal/{ManufacturerName}", defaults: new { controller = "Deal", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
            routes.MapRoute("Home", "Home", defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
            routes.MapRoute("SpecialGarage", "SpecialsGarrage", defaults: new { controller = "Deal", action = "SpecialsGarrage" });
            routes.MapRoute("TotalCare", "TotalCare", defaults: new { controller = "Deal", action = "TotalCare" });
            routes.MapRoute("GreanDeal", "GreanDeal", defaults: new { controller = "Deal", action = "GreanDeal" });
            routes.MapRoute("AboutUs", "AboutUs", defaults: new { controller = "Page", action = "Index" });
            routes.MapRoute("UsefulLinks", "UsefulLinks", defaults: new { controller = "Page", action = "Index" });
            routes.MapRoute("Contact", "Contact", defaults: new { controller = "Contact", action = "Index" });
            routes.MapRoute("WholeLifeCosts", "WholeLifeCosts", defaults: new { controller = "Page", action = "Index" });
            routes.MapRoute("Proposals", "Proposals", defaults: new { controller = "Contact", action = "Proposals" });
            routes.MapRoute("QuickContact", "QuickContact", defaults: new { controller = "Contact", action = "QuickContact" });


            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

when I submit form, it returns the error as

> The matched route does not include a 'controller' route value, which is required.

What have I done wrong in this code?

Comment: Can you show the code in `App_Start\RouteConfig.cs`?

Comment: Hi, I have added route.config code in question.

Comment: Looks like this route is the problem: `routes.MapRoute("Error", "Home/Error");`, what's the controller and action for that route?

Comment: that is in Home controller

Answer (score 1):

You're not specifying the default controller and action for this route

```
routes.MapRoute("Error", "Home/Error");
```

You should specify the default controller and action

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Error",
    url: "Home/Error",
    defaults: new { controller = "YourControllerName", action = "YourActionName" }
    );
```

or you can remove the above route if you want `Home/Error` url to call `Error` action in `Home` controller since the `Home/Error` url will be covered by the default route

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: Thanks. if I give default controller and action for this Error, it is working fine. thanks a lot

Comment: I've updated my answer, in case the default controller isn't `Home` and the default action isn't `Error`. Please consider to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/255183) my answer if you think it solves your problem. I see you haven't accepted any answers yet even though you've posted quite a lot of questions. You should accept the answers that solved your previous questions as well.